# Token Attributes

Tags: c#, architecture, token

I have written simple lexical analyzer. And I understand the need to provide each recognized token with attribute. Let's see what I got:

```
public sealed class Token
{ 
    public enum TokenClass
    { 
        Identifier,
        StringLiteral,
        NumberLiteral,
        Operator,
        PunctuationSeparator,
        Bracket,
        Parenthesis
    }        
    public TokenClass Class { get; internal set; }
    public String     Value { get; internal set; }
}
```

In lexer I enqueue tokens setting up thier value & class. But what about attributes? How should I design the feature relative to my existing token class?

First tought came into my mind was:

1. Declare private abstract classes of "ambiguous-entities" (I mean that Number could be Integer and Real and so on) inside token class;
2. Then declare inherited classes e.g. 
   `public class Comma : PunctuationSeparator {}`;
3. Add Property `Object Attribute {get; private set;}`;
4. Then create method like `private void ApplyAttribute()`;
5. Call `ApplyAttribute()` when token is instantiated and properties are set;
6. Use something like this inside `ApplyAttribute()`.

   ```
   switch(this.TokenClass)
   {
   case this.TokenClass.Number:
       {
           this.Attribute = (Int32.TryParse(this.Value))? new Integer() : new Real();                
       }
   }
   ```

In parser it would be easy to write something like that `if(CurToken.Attribute is Integer)`.
One thing that stops me from doing like that is number of classes I should create. Is this solution acceptable?

Comment: Do you have an ontology of your domain? It should not be the case that you have to make all different kind of empty classes. Did you already create a structure of inheritance? Maybe setting different types of `PunctuationSeperator`s is enough.

Comment: No I haven't yet created anything described here. These are just my plans and doubts. It seems to be useful, but ...classes... I can't decide.. help:) What do you mean saying your last sentence?

Comment: When creating a class like `PunctuationSeperator`. It could be handy to define an enum in there as well, with different puctuations [comma, period, semilocon]. So first, I think you should define how your domain is, before making such a descision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes I'd use for a token? Probably something along the lines of

```
public class Token
{
  public TokenType Type { get ; private set ; }
  public string    Text { get ; private set ; }
  public int       LineNumber { get ; private set ; }
  public int       Column     { get ; private set ; }
}

public enum TokenType
{
  Keyword : 1 ,
  Integer ,
  String  ,
  Whitespace ,
  Comment ,
  ... 
}
```

I disagree, though, with the previous poster regarding conversion of the token's text into a 'value'. IMHO, that is the domain of the parser and the nodes of the parse tree. Until the parser has placed the tokens in context WRT the grammar, the token is just a piece of text with a label attached to it. The lexical analyzer doesn't know (and should care) what's happening downstream -- for all it know, the took is pretty-printing the source text (in which case, you want to leave the individual tokens alone).

You might want to take a look at Terrance Parr's book(s):

- [Language Implementation Patterns: Create Your Own Domain-Specific and General Programming Languages](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns)
- [The Definitive ANTLR Reference: Building Domain-Specific Languages](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference)

Comment: Overviewed the books! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public String Value { get; internal set; }
```

just use

```
public object Value { get; internal set; }
```

and then store integer or floating-point values in there as an integer or floating-point value. Then in your parser you can just say

```
if (token.Value == null)
{
    // blah
}
else if (token.Value is int)
{
    // work with (int) token.Value
}
else if (token.Value is double)
{
    // work with (double) token.Value
}
else if (token.Value is string)
{
    // work with (string) token.Value
}
```

or alternatively:

```
int? integer;
double? floating;
string str;

if (token.Value == null)
{
    // blah
}
else if ((integer = token.Value as int?) != null)
{
    // work with integer.Value
}
else if ((floating = token.Value as double?) != null)
{
    // work with floating.Value
}
else if ((str = token.Value as string) != null)
{
    // work with str
}
```

Comment: That's good with primitive types, but what about parentheses or braces? how do I set up the value?

Comment: @helicera: Firstly, `object` is not limited to primitive types. You can put anything you want in it. But secondly, what kind of “value” do you need for a parenthesis token? I’d expect there to be an `OpenParenthesis` and `CloseParenthesis` token type with a null value. Alternatively, of course, you could have a `PunctuationSymbol` token type and store the `"("` string in `Value`, but personally I would find that hacky.